# Cant connect via Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows, hyper-v, winrm

today i was connected via a Win 10 Admincomputer to one of our Hyper V Servers. Everything worked so far. Then I was about to create a new VM on that HyperV Host. It created the VM and I pressed start, then I was kicked out of the console. When I tried to reconnect via Hyper V Manager. I got the Message: WINRM can not complete your Operation (see screenshot below)

I didnt change any configuration. The Servers and the Admindesktop are in the same subnet.

Checked winrm quickconfig.. No errors. WinRM running well. As well on the Hyper V Host.

Restarted the HyperV Host. Still same error.
[WINRM Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmNv9.png)

Comment: Is the Virtual Machine Management service on the Hyper-V host running? Does Hyper-V Manager on the Hyper-V host work?

Comment: Yes the Mangement Service is running. Just checked it. We dont have Hyper V Manager on the Host. Its without GUI

Comment: Check Network Location Awareness if you're running firewall profiles which depend on NLA knowing it's in a private/domain network.